# How to create a new php file from template

Tags: php

I am certainly not an expert in PHP, and have surfed SO thoroughly but didn't find anything related to this. Might mean that the question is stupid, but I was trying to create a new php file on sign up (so to provide rss feeds for each person who signs up) and I've managed so far to create a beatifully empty file. Here's the code of a test file I have written in the end, with GET function:

```
$USR = $_GET['usr'];
$FILE=$USR.'.rss.php';
$file1 = 'rssdemo.php'; 
$handle = fopen($file1, 'a'); 
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($file1)); 
fclose($handle); 
        $file2 =$FILE; 
        $handle = fopen($file2, 'wb'); 
        fwrite($handle, $contents);  //this should write something but does nothing   
        fclose($handle);
```

As you can see, the file I am trying to copy from is a PHP file (that should in its turn generate the XML file). 
Is there a way to create a new php file, open an old one, copy the content of it and paste it into the newly created file? Or maybe fwrite () can be used for text only? Some help please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to create a file for each user ? Why can't there be a function that gives each user his rss feed according to his username for example? I think the question is not stupid but that it is not well understood what you want to achieve.

Comment: Don't do this! What if you want to update the code in your rss script? Are you going to change the files for your 654642 users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply have one url per user, like this: http://www.example.com/index.php/greg0ire/rss

Use a rewrite rule so that index.php gets called, and analyse the "greg0ire/rss" part to route to an Rss action that has a user parameter, and pass it the "greg0ire" as an argument.

Comment: thank you that's easier than what I was trying to do actually! I have come back because I've found the answer to my own question (and here's the stupid me revealed): 
$USERNAME = $_GET['usr'];
$FILE=$USERNAME.'.rss.php';
$file1 = 'demorss.php';  
$handle1 = fopen($file1, 'a+'); 
$contents = fread($handle1, filesize($file1)); 
        $file2 =$FILE; 
        $handle = fopen($file2, 'wb'); 
        fwrite($handle, $contents);      
        fclose($handle); 
        fclose($handle1); 

        ?>

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use some php template system for example [Templum](http://templum.electricmonk.nl/)  or you can write your own template engine there are alot of tutorials for example [How to make a simple html template engine](http://www.broculos.net/en/article/how-make-simple-html-template-engine-php) . Google tutorials you will find alot of examples for template engines.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the PHP [copy](http://php.net/manual/es/function.copy.php) function:

```
copy("source/file.php", "destination/file.php");
```

Comment: While this is possible, it's a very bad idea to create a PHP file per user.

Comment: I was just answering to "Is there a way to create a new php file, open an old one, copy the content of it and paste it into the newly created file?", but it's true, in this case that's not the best solution.

Comment: thanks this discussion was very helpful. I had seen it somewhere, with a simple function that creates a new file for user generated RSS feeds on subscription, and was trying to create a php file per user, which in fact can go out of control very easily as all of you say. Because though, I couldn't even copy the content of a template file into the new generated file, I thought it was better to ask instead of spending hours wondering (in fact I have just found out I was copying reversed)